# I replaced Bootstrap 3 with Bootstrap 5 and now jQuery will not work Visual Studio

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, bootstrap-5

I have already read through several different questions on StackOverflow regarding this topic, but I cannot seem to find the question pertaining to the issue I am having. I have created a new MVC Solution using .NET Framework and I wanted to rip out Bootstrap 3.x to replace with Bootstrap 5.x. I was able to complete this by swapping out the files and updating the BundleConfig bootstrap and css from

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

to

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Bootstrap 5 works flawlessly, but jQuery does not work anymore. I can note that on Bootstrap's website they mention that Bootstrap 5 gets away from jQuery but will recognize when the browser is utilizing jQuery and will add the proper items to render it correctly. However, when I try to run simple commands in jQuery on my Index.cshtml page such as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
console.log("ready!");
});
```

The DOM states "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Here is what my Bundle Config file looks like:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

and my Layout.cshtml page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Great Lakes Bible Church</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/341cefdc07.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation-section">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Great Lakes Bible Church", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#NavItems" aria-controls="NavItems" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="NavItems">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-md-auto">
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                @Html.ActionLink("What We Believe", "WhatWeBelieve", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Map & Directions", "MapAndDirections", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Ministries", "Ministries", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Sermons and Notes", "SermonsAndNotes", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Meet Our Team", "MeetOutTeam", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Connect With Us", "ConnectWithUs", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Give Online", "GiveOnline", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link" })
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Great-Lakes-Bible-Church-565718963772258/?ref=page_internal"><span class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f footer-icon"></span></a>
            <a><span class="fa-brands fa-instagram footer-icon"></span></a>
            <a><span class="fa-solid fa-envelope footer-icon"></span></a>
            <p>&copy; Copywrite @DateTime.Now.Year Great Lakes Bible Church</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I am also going to add pictures of my Scripts js/bootstrap scripts for reference.

Any help would be great.

[JS Scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dW91.png)

[Bootstrap items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcksX.png)

Comment: make sure latest jquery core library loaded at first place before any other jquery library file.

Comment: Does the jQuery bundle get loaded correctly?

Comment: I'll be honest, I am very new when it comes to looking at bundles and file placement. How could I go about verifying that information?

Comment: Where did you place `$(document).ready(...)` code, is it in another page? If yes, does that page apply this part `@section scripts { <script>/* Your Javascript functions */</script> } `. [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sections)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I can verify that the program loads up and everything appears as it is supposed to. Also when I am utilizing jQuery, intellisense for jQuery appears but the DOM does not recognize it.

Comment: @YongShun I placed the jQuery in a script tag in the Index.cshtml page that goes through the ViewStart.cshtml page. I can see all the elements from Layout.cshtml in the Index.cshtml page other than the jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `ScriptBoundle` and `StyleBoundle` and use a virtual name and not an actual path.

Use `ScriptBoundle` with javascript files, and `StyleBoundle` with css files.

try to update `BundleConfig` with this :

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
    }
}
```

then in `Layout.cshtml` change `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` to `@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")`

Comment: Hello iSR5, thank you for looking into this issue. I applied the changes and when I run the program I get a null refence exception in the layout.cshtml page for @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap"). I looked into that exception and what I am seeing is with bootstrap 5  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")); seems to be the cause. I changed it to  bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")) and it no longer threw the null exception, however jQuery is still broken

Comment: I am almost at the point where I may just rip out jQuery and use vanilla JavaScript lol

Comment: @MatthewBaier ok, this is a nugget issue I believe, uninstall bootstrap, then jqueryval, then jquery nugets, then delete any leftovers (if any). now reinstall jquery, then bootstrap, then jqueryval, use the same code I've provided, clean, and rebuild, and then run.

Comment: Hello @iSR5, I uninstall bootstrap, then jqueryval, then jquery nugets (no leftovers remained), then I reinstalled jquery then Bootstrap 5 then jqueryval and used the same code you provided. I cleaned and built and I am still having the same issues

Comment: @MatthewBaier in the ` _Layout` view, try to move the scripts from the body to the head, and check again.